# passing template render result to another method

Tags: php, symfony

i'm trying to assign `$this->render()` result to a method (this method renders google map's infoWindow/baloon).

I'm using method like this to create this infoWindow:

```
$infoWindow->setContent(<here goes the template>);
```

but passing it like this:

```
$infoWindow->setContent($this->render('WmapFrontBundle:Place:infoWindow.html.twig'));
```

don't work at all. What's the proper way to assign template to a variable or pass it's content to a method ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`renderView()`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/283097db0934e19bf2169ea3024d4f872357fcb8/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php#L74), it returns the rendered template only.

[`render()`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/283097db0934e19bf2169ea3024d4f872357fcb8/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php#L87) returns a [`Response`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/283097db0934e19bf2169ea3024d4f872357fcb8/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.php#L14) object (with the rendered template, headers, etc).